# Importing variables from a namespace object in Python

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

Say I have a namespace `args` that I obtain from calling `parser.parse_args()`, which parses the command line arguments.

How can I import all variables from this namespace to my current namespace?

e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--some_parameter', default=1)

args = parser.parse_args()

# ... code to load all variables defined in the namespace args ...

print some_parameter
```

I could certainly do:

```
some_parameter = args.some_parameter
```

but if I have a large number of parameters I would need one such line for each parameter.

Is there another way of importing variables from a namespace without having to go through them one by one?

**PS**: `from args import *` does not work.

**PS2**: I am aware that this is a bad practice, but this can help in some corner cases, such us when prototyping code and tests **very** quickly.

Comment: You could loop over `__dict__` or use `inspect`...

Comment: Or just `locals().update(namespace._get_kwargs())`.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to do this? Why not just access `args.some_parameter`? (Especially since, in a non-trivial program, you're probably going to want to pass the options to other functions, which means if you've got lots of options you're probably going to end up building a `dict` or other object equivalent to the namespace you pulled apart…)

Comment: you can also use `vars(args)` to get a `dict`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your local namespace with the result of the [`vars()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
globals().update(vars(args))
```

This is generally *not* that great an idea; leave those attributes in the namespace instead.

You could create more problems than you solved with this approach, especially if you accidentally configure arguments with a [`dest` name](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) that shadows a built-in or local you care about, such as `list` or `print` or something. Have fun hunting down *that* bug!

Tim Peters already stated this in his Zen of Python:

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: +1. I forgot that `vars(namespace)` and `namespace._get_kwargs()` will return the same thing.

Comment: It's not merely a bad idea that makes for hard-to-read code--it's also a rich source of unintended bugs and security holes. You could easily overwrite globals and builtins--e.g. suppose you have a parameter named `list`? Or a parameter which can't be an identifier, like `2my-param`?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: It's not necessarily a security hole, provided the parser has been set up with sane argument names. You cannot inject *arbitrary* argument destinations in any case. Besides, the user of this program already has local-user access to be able to run it..

Comment: tsk,tsk.  You shouldn't modify `locals`.  quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: @mgilson: That mostly applies to functions; grab a parent function in the current call stack and try to update it's `f_locals` structure with new values for example and it'll fail.. But for modules (where `locals()` == `globals()` anyway, it'll work just fine. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- my understanding is that anywhere where `locals != globals`, it will fail -- in which case, you might as well change your answer to be `globals` instead of `locals` and not pretend like `locals` that works for this -- But that's just my opinion ... (the rest of the answer is good)

Comment: @mgilson: No, in many/most places `locals()` is actually writable (including adding *new* keys), but I'll update it to use `globals()` instead.

Comment: FYI -- I came across this in another question which referenced it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716727/picklable-data-containers-that-are-dumpable-in-the-current-namespace/14716991#14716991).  I solved the "general" problem using an `exec` hack with a broad disclaimer that it isn't what OP actually wants to do.

Comment: @mgilson: but, but, `exec` updates `locals()` just as much.. When you omit both globals and locals from the statement, the C code just runs `PyEval_GetLocals`, *exactly* what `locals()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the worst idea ever: since you can pass an arbitrary object to `parse_args()`, pass the `__builtins__` module, so that all attributes can be looked up as local variables.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--foo")
p.parse_args( "--foo bar".split(), __builtins__)
print foo
```

This will even "work" for parameters whose destinations aren't valid Python identifiers:

```
# To use the example given by Francis Avila in his comment on Martijn Pieters' answer
getattr(__builtins__, '2my-param')
```